# Configure the boot menu in a dual boot system

Tags: boot

I have installed Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.04. The problem is that once I turn on the PC the boot menu is completely messed up.

Sometimes it appears the typical black menu and sometimes it loads Windows first and then the menu appears blue with two options, 1 Ubuntu and 2 Ubuntu!

If I choose the first Ubuntu it loads Windows and if I choose the second Ubuntu it restarts and then starts Ubuntu.

The menu itself was configured using EasyBCD.

How can I configure the menu correctly with or without EasyBCD?

Comment: A screenshot of `EasyBCD` would be helpful to verify your configuration is correct.